# How important is it for a professor to direct a thesis?

Tags: thesis, mathematics, advisor, undergraduate

How important is it for a professor to direct a thesis?

I mean, what can the professor get from it? I know it will help for his/her curriculum, but is it too much?

Is the merit equivalent to the publication of an article?

or is it not so important?

or is it more important than the publication of any article?

I am just curious about it.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question is very much dependent on field, the type of university where the prof works and the carrier stage of the professor. Do you want to narrow some of these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the other answers here disturb me. It is as if the academic life is nothing more than building up a big pile of personal *chits* and deviously inducing others (students) to add more chits to your pile. I reject that view and have never witnessed it in a career that began in the 1970s.

As a professor, I was mostly concerned with finding truth in a narrow area. Any publications were a means to spread the knowledge that I learned along with colleagues.

For most of my career I wasn't involved in doctoral education. But in the final decade or so I had a few doctoral students. They are my academic children and will, I hope, carry on that search for truth that I participated in.

My own teachers, including my dissertation advisor, were, in my view, giants, who helped me grow and become myself. They *got* nothing out of it but the knowledge that I learned and appreciated their efforts. I was lucky enough to have the opportunity to go back and personally thank one of my mentors before he died. He noted that such things happen too seldom.

In mathematics we have something called the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu) through which PhDs can trace their mathematical ancestry. We are proud to be the intellectual children of our advisors and we are equally proud to be the intellectual parents of our students.

It is actually the fulfillment of the profession. No chits needed. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: true, but the question included the undergraduate tag, so I assumed it referred primarily to Bachelor's and Master's thesis rather than a PhD thesis. These are often rewarding to, as I mentioned in my answer. However, these are less my "academic children", if only because they are done so much quicker than a PhD thesis, so I spent much less time with them and most of them won't continue in academia.

Answer (score 4):

Advising a bachelor or master's thesis is just part of my teaching obligation. Most of the time it is an enjoyable obligation: now I get to accompany someone on their first steps in doing independent research. However, that is pretty much all I get out of it. Advising a PhD thesis is a bit more prestigious, but the added value drops quickly. However, with a PhD project the advisor may get one or two co-authored papers out of it, and in some disciplines the PhD students are an important source of cheap labor.

Comment: I spoke to a professor who got a deal at his new institution to not have to teach for the first year. At first she thought this was great, but in the end she regretted it because it delayed the influx of new PhD students as well. So in that sense advising bachelor and master theses also has some indirect benefits.

Comment: @Keelan good point. Though in my institution we typically start recruiting way before the bachelor or master's thesis. What happens is the early big lectures of the first year, we select the most promising students for tutor and assistant jobs. It is from this pool that we do most of the recruiting. So the person teaching the early big lectures tends to be in the best position to spot the promising students (though it will take a couple of years before they become available)

Answer (score 1):

In some fields, directing a Ph.D. student means you get cheap labor for your lab.  But in non-lab subjects, I tend to agree with Maarten.  Directing a Ph.D. may enhance your reputation.  Within your department it may be taken into account for raises or promotions.  Outside your department, you benefit if it becomes known that your former Ph.D.s go on to big things.

Comment: in this case it's for Bachelor's thesis not Ph.D.